# Haskell base-4.x package installation

Tags: haskell, package, cabal

when I try to install this package http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.1.0.0

by running:

runhaskell Setup configure

I am getting this error:

attempting to use module `System.IO' (System/IO.hs) which is not loaded

Not in scope: `System.IO.stderr'

Not in scope: `System.IO.stdin'
ghc-6.8.2: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 6.8.2 for i386-unknown-linux):
    interactiveUI:setBuffering

Any ideas what might be wrong? Also when I cd to the directory with the files and type ghci I am getting the same error but ghci works in general.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can't upgrade the base package -- you have to upgrade your GHC. Just grab the latest GHC from the Haskell Platform: http://haskell.org/platform

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to upgrade your GHC not base. Base-4.* is attached to latest GHC.

Latest GHC is available at [here](http://haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_6_10_4.html).

The error you got is when runhaskell compiled Setup.lhs, he was confused with existing System.IO and System.IO under the current directory. To avoid this, you would need to upgrade your GHC. BTW, I don't know how to upgrade base without upgrading GHC. But base depends compiler, not any particular package. So I guess it can't.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing cabal-install first. After that you should be able to do "cabal install base-4.1.0" and it will automatically install all required dependencies before proceeding with install.